# Credential storage in client library unit-testing

Tags: .net, unit-testing, open-source, tfs, credentials

I just started an open-source project for an Azure table storage client on codeplex called [Cyan](http://cyannet.codeplex.com).

I would like to include unit-tests for the project but I don't know what's the best way to store credentials for the tests so that any contributor can use his ones without the risk of checking them in the public source control.

Any advice/best practice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I know works great (at least with regular TFS) is to put the unittests into a seperate folder structure and then to customize the permissions on the folder structure (or maybe this is only limited to some specific files) to not let contributors modify those folders. Then you have explicit control over the content of those assets that you need.

What you can also try is to have those credentials stored in files that are not under version control. For a contributor to mess up then involves an explicit add action which can be prevented, by exclusion of that specific file type or by a custom check-in policy, like forbidden-pattern.

Comment: The second one could solve it, I could keep credentials in a file outside of the solution but in the path of the test project.